# @@FETCH_STATUS lives outside the cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a query which processes XML data and I use a `while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)` loop for data returned from the cursor.

When I run the query using Management Studio, `@@FETCH_STATUS` equals -1 and the code inside my loop is omitted. If I run the query using the debugger and press continue, it runs just fine and the `@@FETCH_STATUS` equals 0. When I run the query again, after running it in debug `@@FETCH_STATUS` equals 0 and changes to -1.

To sum up:

1. I run with SSMS - `@@FETCH_STATUS = -1`
2. I run with debugger - `@@FETCH_STATUS = 0` (I want this value)
3. I run with SSMS once after running with debugger `@@FETCH_STATUS` still equals 0 but then changes to -1.

I use `OPEN cursor`, `CLOSE cursor` and `DEALLOCATE cursor`. Why does it work this way?

EDIT: Code you asked for:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.XmlOrderResponses') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE XmlOrderResponses;

CREATE TABLE XmlOrderResponses (
    OrderResponseType INT
    ,OrderResponseNumber NVARCHAR(40)
    ,OrderResponseDate DATETIME
    ,DocumentFunctionCode NVARCHAR(40)
    ,Remarks INT
    );

DECLARE CUR CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Subdirectory
FROM XMLFiles;

OPEN CUR

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DocHandle AS INT;
    DECLARE @TMP AS NVARCHAR(512);

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM Cur
    INTO @TMP

    DECLARE @XmlDocument AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @XmlDocument = (
            SELECT CAST(XMLSource AS NVARCHAR(max))
            FROM XMLFiles
            WHERE subdirectory = @TMP
            );

    EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT
        ,@XmlDocument;

    INSERT INTO XmlOrderResponses (
        OrderResponseType
        ,OrderResponseNumber
        ,OrderResponseDate
        ,DocumentFunctionCode
        ,Remarks
    )
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@DocHandle, '/Document-OrderResponse/*', 11) WITH (
        OrderResponseType INT
        ,OrderResponseNumber NVARCHAR(40)
        ,OrderResponseDate DATETIME
        ,DocumentFunctionCode NVARCHAR(40)
        ,Remarks INT
        );

    EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle;
END

CLOSE CUR;

DEALLOCATE CUR;

--I know I shouldn't be doing that but I can't get rid of NULL records the other way.
DELETE
FROM XmlOrderResponses
WHERE OrderResponseType IS NULL
    AND OrderResponseNumber IS NULL
    AND OrderResponseDate IS NULL
    AND DocumentFunctionCode IS NULL
    AND Remarks IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM XmlOrderResponses

SELECT @@FETCH_STATUS
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code to understand what you are asking. Can you post the SQL?

Comment: Remember `@@FETCH_STATUS` is global to all cursors on a connection, so other cursors running on the same connection can change @@FETCH_STATUS even if the cursor you are currently "viewing" has not changed status. This can be especially problematic when debugging due to the prolongued nature of execution with breakpoints. You may wish to use  - `SELECT [fetch_status] FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID) WHERE Name = 'YourCursorName'` instead of `@@FETCH_STATUS`.

Comment: And when you post your code we could even check if you really need the cursor? :)

Comment: I added the code you asked for. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: You should only examine `@@FETCH_STATUS` *after* you've actually performed a `FETCH` on a cursor. This almost always means that you need to duplicate your `FETCH` - having one above the loop and the other at the end (but inside) the loop.

Comment: Could you provide me with a better idea to design this query? I have prior experience with Firebird and I wanted to kind of copy Firebird's FOR SELECT DO BEGIN. Here I wanted to use WHILE but as far as I know I needed a cursor (which is considered a bad practice).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the first time you refer to `@@FETCH_STATUS`, you have not done a fetch with your cursor, so it is referring to the last cursor used. Imagine this simple example:

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT TOP 3 ID
    FROM (VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3')) t (ID);

OPEN C1;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c1 CHAR(1);
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @c1;
    PRINT @c1;
END

CLOSE C1;
DEALLOCATE C1;

DECLARE C2 CURSOR 
FOR 
    SELECT TOP 3 ID
    FROM (VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3')) t (ID);

OPEN C2;

-- HERE @@FETCH_STATUS REFERS TO THE LAST FETCH FOR CURSOR `C1` NOT `C2`
SELECT @@FETCH_STATUS;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c2 CHAR(1);
    FETCH NEXT FROM C2 INTO @c2;
    PRINT @c2;
END;

CLOSE C2;
DEALLOCATE C2;
```

At the commented line, even though you have closed, and deallocated `C1`, `@@FETCH_STATUS` is still referring to this cursor (since no other `FETCH` has been performed since), so you never enter your loop for `C2`

You should perform the Fetch before the loop, then at the end of each loop, rather than at the beginning.

```
DECLARE @TMP AS NVARCHAR(512);
OPEN CUR
-- DO FETCH FIRST
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @TMP

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DocHandle AS INT;

    -- DO ALL YOUR WORK WITH @TMP


    --PERFORM THE FETCH AGAIN AT THE END OF THE LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @TMP
END
```

The other problem you have with doing `FETCH` at the start of each loop, is that the last item will be processed twice. Again a simple example (and assuming you enter the loop with @@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR 
FOR
    SELECT ID = '1';

OPEN C1;
DECLARE @c CHAR(1);
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c1 CHAR(1);
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @c1;
    PRINT @c1;
END
```

This will print

```
1
1
```

Because, when `@@FETCH_STATUS` is -1, `FETCH` will just return the item at the current position.

Comment: I understand the issue now. Can you come up with a smarter solution to my problem? I can't just "reset" the @@FETCH_STATUS as it is a system variable.